# how serialize in code behind and de serialize in JavaScript then serialize in JavaScript and de serialize in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, serialization

I use web service and know how to send and receive string between code behind and JavaScript.
but now I have a 2D array and xml that I need to send and receive between code behind and JavaScript.

so:
1 - Is serialize and send a string is the best way?
2 - how can I do it?

Comment: JSON for the array, XML for the XML.

Comment: thanks. what is the syntax? or any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**to serialize in code behind:**

```
Dim serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim createArrayScript As String = serializer.Serialize("{for example my array}")
```

**to de serialize in JavaScript**
download and use json-serialization.js from below linkg:
then:

```
var obj = JSON.parse("{received string from code behind}");
```

**to serialize in javascript**
download and use json-serialization.js from below linkg:
then:

```
var str = JSON.stringify("{for example my array}");
```

**to de serialize in code behind:**

```
 Dim my_array As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)("{received   string from javaScript}")
```

I think this method convert 2d array to simple one, this site json.codeplex.com/ says his solution is better, but i didn't check.
for more information:
http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Kian Fatt, Ting] I think you can use DWR for java script, DWR allows you to store your data in a database table to later retrieve it back would that solve your problem?

Comment: you mean serialize and send via string is not best way? where can i receive information about DWR?